# TypeORM: update on conflict without id

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, typeorm

I'd like to bulk `insert` or `update` if `exists` rows in a table without prior knowledge of the `id` of the row if it exists. I'm using `TypeORM`. In this case, I want to `update` rows where the `uniqueKey` exists with a new `title`, and `insert` where it does not.

```
const data = [
  {title: 'New Title', user: 123, uniqueKey: 'abc'},
  {title: 'Another New Title', user: 123, uniqueKey: 'xyz' }
 ]

await repo
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Posts)
    .values(data)
    .orUpdate({ conflict_target: ['uniqueKey'], overwrite: ['title']  })
    .execute();
```

The above throws the error:

```
Error: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.
```

Open to suggestions if there is a better way of doing this for a bulk `upsert`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is always to not hide the SQL database, as far as I'm concerned.

Building a query with transparent functions might even prevent you from doing what I am doing here in plain SQL (I don't know about node.js, but other SQL wrappers choked on me with this one ...)

Oh, and `user` is a reserved word; it contains the name of the user currently connected to MySQL ..

```
INSERT INTO posts (title,userid,unique_key)
VALUES ('New Title'        , 123, 'abc')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title='New Title';

INSERT INTO posts (title,userid,unique_key)
VALUES ('Another New Title', 123, 'xyz')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title='Another New Title';
```

Or, for a mass insert, fill a temporary table, same structure as `posts`, and then:

```
INSERT INTO posts (title,userid,unique_key)
SELECT
  title
, userid
, unique_key
FROM posts_tmp t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = t.title, userid=t.userid;
```

Comment: Creating temporary tables will not scale well if this will run often

Comment: Then keep the table permanent, and truncate it at the end of the process....

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when trying to bulk .orUpdate an array of objects that did not have 'id' fields. All I had to do was add id fields to each object I import since I believe it's used for iterating through 'metadata' of each object when doing .orUpdate.

I use MySQL as well and here is the code in my case (url being the uniqueKey):

```
 const result = await connection
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Channel)
    .values(data)
    .orUpdate({
      conflict_target: ["url"],
      overwrite: ["name", "imgurl", "subscribers"],
    }) //If channel exists we update its info.
    .execute()
    .catch((err) => err);
```

I would get the same error you mentioned when my objects were of this structure:

```
data = [{name : "name", imgurl : "imgurl", url: "url1"}, { name : "name", imgurl : "imgurl", url: "url2"}]
```

Iterating through the array of objects and adding incremental id's to each solved the issue:

```
data = [{id: 1, name : "name", imgurl : "imgurl", url: "url1"}, {id: 2, name : "name", imgurl : "imgurl", url: "url2"}]
```

Hopefully this can be a temp fix for you at the very least.